# With ImageMagick, how can you see all available fonts?

Tags: image-manipulation, imagemagick, text2image

ImageMagick can draw text into a picture in a given font, how can I see all available fonts for my system?

Answer (score 136, accepted):

depending on your imagemagick version:

```
convert -list type       # for IM older than v6.3.5-7
convert -list font       # for newer versions
```

also the output format changed...

-- update For OsX (Answer from Charles Merriam) if the command above does not produce any results:

For a full tutorial with description see http://gothick.org.uk/2008/03/14/using-os-x-fonts-in-imagemagick/ for the rest &tldr:

```
# use fondu to convert fonts and update locatedb
sudo port install fondu 
cd /usr/local/share/fonts/
fondu /Library/Fonts/*.dfont
/etc/periodic/weekly/310.locate

# generate imagemagick type.xml 
cd ~
mkdir ~/.magick
wget http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/scripts/imagick_type_gen
perl imagick_type_gen > ~/.magick/type.xml
```

Comment: What do you do if `convert -list font` prints nothing?

Comment: I upgraded from imagemagick 6.8.7-7 to 6.8.9-7 which did the trick for me.

Comment: is it possible to list fonts for a particular language ?

Comment: The above answer is not correct. For `convert -list fonts` to work, the fonts need to be in the type.xml file for ImageMagick. To get all your compatible fonts in the type.xml file, see my answer below.

Answer (score 12):

To list only the font names, do `convert -list font | grep Font`

Answer (score 10):

The fonts are a bit tricky.   ImageMagick will not usually 'see' your system fonts.   On OS/X, fonts are stored in a non-standard format.

Use `convert -list font` to see the fonts ImageMagick currently knows about.   It may be blank.

ImageMagick looks for `$HOME/.magick/type.xml` for the list of fonts.  If you are on OS/X, go see the well written tutorial at http://gothick.org.uk/2008/03/14/using-os-x-fonts-in-imagemagick/.

Answer (score 2):

Your OS file system will list all your fonts.

But if you are asking about fonts that Imagemagick knows about for use by name, then use `convert -list font` to see all those fonts listed in its type.xml file.

If that shows nothing, then if you are on a unix-like platform, you can use the perl script by Anthony Thyssen to install your fonts into the type.xml file rather than doing them by hand. See https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/scripts/imagick_type_gen.

Then doing `convert -list font` should list the ones that Imagemagick recognizes and you can then use them by name `-font fontname` . Otherwise, you need to provide the full path to the font file `-font path/to/font.suffx`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have recently installed a font which is not appearing when using:

`convert -list font`

You can flush your font cache with:

`fc-cache -f -v`

Answer (score -2):

I find the **gnome-font-viewer** more useful to see all the fonts visually compared to a list of names returned on the command line.