# How to get Imagick to list available fonts

Tags: php, imagick

I'm trying to get Imagick to list all fonts in PHP.  I found the following code in the PHP.net manual:

```
$fontList = \Imagick::queryFonts("*");

foreach ($fontList as $fontName) {
 $output .= '<li>'. $fontName."</li>";
}

return $output;
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work for me. I get the following PHP error which I don't understand:

```
Strict Standards: Non-static method Imagick::queryfonts() should not be called statically
```

Anyone have a suggestion? thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392858/with-imagemagick-how-can-you-see-all-available-fonts

Comment: @Progrock You have linked to an answer about the command line ImageMagick utilities. Which is not the same as Imagick, the PHP extension.

Comment: @Danack true.  The Convert program is a member of the ImageMagick suite of tools.  So is likely to be there.  Not a pure Php solution, but may provide an alternative method.

Comment: I notice that the example above was a quote from the manual.  http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.queryfonts.php

Comment: And the manual reflects the current version, not a 3 year old version of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're apparently using a quite old version of Imagick. The queryFonts method was made to be callable by a static call back on Sep 25, 2013.

If you can't upgrade to a later version, you should be able to do:

```
$imagick = new Imagick();
$fonts = $imagick->queryfonts();
```